# How to make image fadeOut without getting affected by the hover on my div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I have 2 divs on my page, and each div must show image upon hover.

```
<div class="link1container">
    <div class="link1 animated bounceInLeft">
        <a href="#"><h1> What</h1></a>
    </div>
    <div class="link1hover">
        <img src="http://static.rappler.com/images/Convergys-Stream-Twitter-20140304.jpg">
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="link2container">                        
    <div class="link2 animated bounceInDown">
        <a href="#"><h2>drives</h2></a>
    </div>                                                  
    <div class="link2hover">
        <img src="http://images.gmanews.tv/v3/webpics/v3/2014/02/2014_02_13_09_54_25.jpg">           
    </div>
</div>
```

And this

```
$('.link1container').hover(function(){
    $('.link1hover').fadeIn(200)
},function(){
    $('.link1hover').fadeOut(200)
})


$('.link2container').hover(function(){
    $('.link2hover').fadeIn(200)
},function(){
    $('.link2hover').fadeOut(500)
})
```

The problem is, when I hover the first image, before it finally fades out, it appears. The second div is being covered by it, so the second image does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

It's because u are using event on wrapping container `$('.link1container').` Try use it on link directly `$('.link1')`.

btw there is no need to use jQuery at all

```js
img {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .2s linear;

}

[class*=link]:hover + [class*=link] img {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: I am new to jQuery, I just realized I could use css instead.

Comment: Of course, everything that you can do with styles, better do with styles. Is it an answer on your question? If it so, please mark it